# Web API AuthorizeAttribute does not return custom response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I make IsAuthorized return my custom object while function returns false?

In my WebAPI project I have a class like;

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            StandardWebAPIResponse invalidUserResponse = new StandardWebAPIResponse()
                    {
                        code = (int) Constants.ErrorCodes.InvalidCredentials,
                        data = "InvalidCredentials.",
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                    };
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                        invalidUserResponse);
                    // if I set this to true I am getting 401 with my custom object
                    // otherwise it gives me default error message 
                    // {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
                    return false;
        }
    }
```

For some reason when I return false from IsAuthorized function, it does not return my custom invalidUserResponse object. But if I return true it returns it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should override the OnAuthorization method, that use the IsAuthorized and flushs the response, or force a flush at your method.

Comment: How can I flush response, thus I could not find that function/option.

Comment: Yeah, I checked, they took .End() away from the Http namespace. You should override the OnAuthorization then, makes more sense fill the response there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. You can make your comments as a response then I can mark as an answer. It may help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `OnAuthorization` method, that use the `IsAuthorized` and flushs the `response`, or force a flush at your method. Makes more sense fill the response where the filter manipulates It.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question has been answered but I feel like it is slightly wrong. I don't think that a message for unauthorized request should be handled by `OnAuthorization` but should be handled by `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`. I'm not sure if it will cause any major problems putting it in `OnAuthorization`, but presumably the reason you were getting the message when true and not false is because the base class writes over your response in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

It is a subtle thing but the `OnAuthorization` directs to the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` for a reason. It is mainly a separation of responsibilities thing, but if you ever want to do more than just sending an error message, like log bad request your `OnAuthorization` method will probably get crowded. You should used the methods given to you for clarity sake if nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I agree. You would need to implement custom filter derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
        Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(ErrorMessage),
        new ErrorMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            Message = Constants.UnauthorisedErrorMessage,
            ErrorCode = Constants.UnauthorisedErrorCode
        }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will re-arrange my logic this way.